# Applying style to nested pages in a master page

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

Why could I be unable to apply style on a nested page which is using a master page? I am just trying to apply simple some back-color to body and some div in an individual page.

My (nested)page `Reservations.aspx` has this code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Reservations.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reservations" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link href="~/Styles/input.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div class="mainDiv">
........
</div></asp:Content>
```

`input.cs` has this code

```
body { background-color:Silver; }
.mainDiv { background-color:Blue; }
```

`Site.Master` has this code

```
<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
<body>.........
```

I can get Silver Color as background of `Reservations.aspx` only if I apply this to master page which I do not want. I have not been able to get helped from accepted answer of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522200/asp-net-master-pages-style-sheet-per-page) and tutorials.

**Edit**

using `<link..` before or after might make some difference, thanks for info but it is not doing anything in this case. I have tested it both ways after my problem was solved.

**Guidance to `ResolveUrl` solved my problem**, because I tried using `pickurl` in `visual-studio 2010` instead of typing manually and got this url `Styles/input.css` instead of `~/Styles/input.css`.

**Update => How it was Solved**

`href="Styles/Site.css"` or `href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/Site.css")%>'`

Comment: Can you show what css rules you have in your `Site.css`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use resolve url as follows.

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/")%>
```

as follows

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/Site.css")%>'  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Working when your `Master Page` and `Content Page` are on the same folder then any include in the master page will work.

But when your `Master Page` and `Content Page` are in different folder it will not find the same  style sheet or java-script file because **files** are not in the same folder.

So Resolve Url resolve the URL on the server.

Comment: In master page? Ok. It think Yes. But should `<%` not need to be closed? As it is causing problem. So how and where to close it?

Comment: Look into my answer please. After that you might edit and make your answer best.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<head runat="server">

<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
```

Put your ContentPlaceHolder after `<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

As I guess, your stylesheet is applying but it is overriding due to `site.css` which is the nature or css. because when page will render you will get, your `input.css` link tag and after it `site.css` link tag.

So, as Css rule, if site.css is also have css rule for same selector which are in previous css files, the rule which come very last will apply.

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/input.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in your `Reservations.aspx` is solving your issue.

As you were having `href="~/Styles/input.css"`, this url is useful when we are making our resource to relative to our website or webapplication root. the url starting with `~` define that the url is root level url. but it will not render in correct path until this path not render by server side.

for rendering in on server side you can make your link to `runat="server"` with an id. or use `ResolveUrl` method in server side delimiters.

like

```
<link href="~/Styles/input.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="l1" runat="server" />
```

or

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/input.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Ok I do. It might solve my problem. thanks, But can you tell also some reason for it?

Comment: Sorry it did not make a difference. Also i have no `body{}` and `.mainDiv{}` in `Site.css`

Comment: @Sami, Ok, check the url render in the browser is correct or not if not then try using `<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/input.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in your `Reservations.aspx` page.

Comment: Look into my answer please. You might edit and make your answer best.

Answer (score 1):

Move the line:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Below:

```
<link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
```

So that your site.aster reads

```
<link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This way your style sheet in the pages will be read **after** the main one, and should override any settings in there with the page specific one.

However, I'd look to use just the one main style sheet, and then use id's and classes for specific styling needs.

*****EDIT TO ADD FOR FINAL QUESTION*****

The tilde character `~` in asp.net is a symbol to be relative to the path root of the application...

So if you're calling the file from "/stuff/images/somepage.aspx" then even the reference "~/css/style.css" will call "/css/style.css" regardless - If you just call "css/style.css" it will try and find it relative to the current document, i.e. "/stuff/images/css/style.css".

However the `~` character only works in ASP.NET code, so a HTML elemant with it means nothing - only if you use it in a `response.write`, `<%= %>`, `Resolve` or in code behind will it have any meaning.

My *trick* is to use a leading slash for these paths, so "/css/style.css" as this will always reference the file from the root of the URL - as long as you do not deploy into a sub-directory, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

**Update--**

Important point to note that the `<body>` tag is a container of the rest of your tags. Your child page is a part of your body tag. I see that you are trying to specify background to the body tag depending on the child page, but **NO** this is not possible. Because even though you try to download the css specific to your child page, all of it goes into the head tag, so only the last specified css rule for the `<body>` works. On the other end this is not the case with child page elements because they are unique to your child page.

---

This is because the style attributes of Site.css override the attributes of input.css.

This is how your final code is rendered in your browser--

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"> //Master page's markup

    <!-- <asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"> --> //child page markup
          <link href="~/Styles/input.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- </asp:Content> -->

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head> //Master page's markup (the css of Site.css should be overriding your input.css)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem was solved bit differently. Going to post answer.

Comment: Look into my answer please. You might edit and make your answer best.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN ASP.NET Web Site Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tells

`A site-root relative path, which is resolved against the site root.
    Site-root relative paths are useful if you keep resources that are
    used throughout the site, such as images or client script files,
    in a folder that is located under the Web site root.` Example

```
<img src="Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

And

`The ~ operator used to specify a root-relative path for an image when using
    the Image server control In this example, the image file is read from the
    Images folder that is located directly under the root of the Web application,
    regardless of where in the Web site the page is located.`  Example

```
<asp:image runat="server" id="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

As css is not a server side control so we should not use `~` operator with path

Answer (score 0):

You should check the url render in the browser is correct or not if not then try using `<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/input.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in your Reservations.aspx page is solving your issue.

As you were having `href="~/Styles/input.css"`, this url is useful when we are making our resource to relative to our website or webapplication root. the url starting with ~ define that the url is root level url. but it will not render in correct path until this path not render by server side.

For rendering in on server side you can make your link to `runat="server"` with an id. or use `ResolveUrl` method in server side delimiters.